# Runtime dynamic recursion depth on variable size tensors

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, what is the simplest way to recursively apply a set of ops where each recursive step takes as input the output of the last step? The critical feature here is that the number of recursion steps is specified at evaluation, and can vary between examples.

For example, for input tensors `X`, `5`, and some function `F`, I'd like to compute

`F( F( F( F( F(X) ) ) ) )`

But the same model should also be able to compute `X`, `3` as:

`F( F( F( X ) ) )`

Unfortunately, while loops will not work, because they enforce strict shape invariants, meaning that all dimensions of tensor X have to be known at compile time, but I won't know the example size (first dimension of X) until runtime.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is easily achieved in TensorFlow using while loops, namely the [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop) construct. `tf.while_loop` has a `shape_invariants` parameter, which lets you specify a (possibly partial) shape for every loop  variable. That shape only has to be less specific than the shape that loop variable can take during the loop. Here is a complete example where `F` is appending a value to a tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.constant(0, shape=[0], dtype=tf.int32)

i, x = tf.while_loop(lambda i, _: i < 10,
                     lambda i, x: (i + 1, tf.concat_v2([x, tf.expand_dims(i, 0)], 0)),
                     [i, x],
                     shape_variants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None])])

print(x.eval())

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: Thanks! Clearly I did not read the documentation closely enough.